# Pandas Type error while graphing pairplot in Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a pandas DataFrame created from a file with the columns ['Time','Q1','Q2','T1','T2']. This works when I try to plot a lineplot:

```py
sns.lineplot(x=data4['Time'], y=data4['Q1'], label='Q1')
```

However when I do a pairplot:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data4, columns=data4.columns)
sns.pairplot(df['Q1'], df['T1'])
```

I get the following error:
`'data' must be pandas DataFrame object, not: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn generally expects a dataframe as its inputs. [According to the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html), the data is the only positional argument and should be a Pandas dataframe with the columns representing different variables and the rows representing different samples.

When one column is selected using the `df["Q1"]` syntax, a `Pandas.Series` object is created while when we create a copy of the dataframe using a list of column names (`df[["Q1", "T1"]]`) a new dataframe is created.

---

TLDR:
Use `sns.pairplot(df[["Q1", "T1"]])` to provide only those two columns to seaborn, or specify the `x` and `y` columns: `sns.pairplot(df, x_vars=["Q1"], y_vars=["T1"])`